# Ambiguous use of 'fetch' error

Tags: swift, core-data

I am using SWIFT 3.0 on Xcode 8.0
I am trying to loop through the fetched results that was created through template.

```
let request = model.fetchRequestTemplate(forName: "template")

do {
    let result = try context.fetch(request!) // Error on this line
    for item: EntityClassName in result! {
        ...
    }
} catch {
    ...
}
```

I get the error "Ambiguous use of 'fetch'". Is my approach wrong? If so what is the right way to loop through the fetched results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `fetch` you are using returns `[Any]`, because it could be `[Dictionary]` or `[NSManagedObject]` or one of its subclasses.

You have to cast `[Any]` to the proper type

```
let result = try context.fetch(request!) as! [EntityClassName]
for item in result {
    ...
}
```

The forced unwrapping is absolutely safe because according to the fetch request it returns always `[EntityClassName]`.

Swift 3 reveals a lot of mistakes made but tolerated in Swift 2 to improve the type safety.

Alternatively you could use the new API with generics, this avoids some type casting.

Comment: I had to change it to { let result = try (context.fetch(request!))! as! [EntityClassName] } but your suggestion helped a lot. Thank you.

Comment: The additional parentheses and exclamation mark are actually not needed. Consider to use the new generic API.

Answer (score 0):

```
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<EntityClassName> = model.fetchRequestTemplate(forName: "template")

do {
    let result = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
    for item in result {
        ...
    }    
} catch {
    ...
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.[From review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/15068573)